Ateji indication in kokugo headwords
I couldn't seem to find a helpful answer anywhere so I might as well ask here.
In monolingual dictionaries, how is ateji indicated in the headwords? Is there a sort-of standard? E.g. in the sankoku (三省堂国語辞典　第八版）I sometimes see red brackets () around part of the kanji, or all the kanji in a word. Does that indicate ateji, or something else like gikun/jukujikun. In the cases I am talking about, additional information is not given in the gloss.

Thank you in advance

Different dictionaries use different notations, and such rules are described in the 凡例 section of each dictionary. Here's a summary article:
串刺し凡例：辞書の紙面ルールまとめ
https://note.com/nishinerima/n/n09e5435b2120
In your dictionary, the × symbol indicates 姥 is a kanji not listed in the jōyō kanji list.
